# Finding coefficient of a term in polynomial

Tags: polynomials

> Consider a polynomial $P(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, with degree $2023$, such that $P(\sin^2(x))+P(\cos^2(x)) =1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If the sum of all roots of $P$ is equal to $\dfrac{p}{q}$ with $p, q$ coprime, then what is the product $pq$?

---

I found a solution here. It goes like this:

> Since polynomial, this implies $P(x)+P(1-x)=1$ $\forall x$. Let $P(x)=ax^{2023}+bx^{2022}+... $ (with $a\ne 0$). Coefficient pf $x^{2022}$ in $P(x)+P(1-x)$ is $2023a+2b$ and must be zero and so $-\frac ba=\frac{2023}2$ Hence result $\boxed{4046}$

---

Can anybody explain how they got coefficient of $x^{2022}$ in $P(x)+P(1-x)$ to be $2023a+2b$? If I'm not wrong, with the notations used in the solution, $P(x)+P(1-x)= a[x^{2023}+(1-x)^{2023}+b[x^{2022}+(1-x)^{2022}+...$. Thank you.

Comment: You're doing fine so far ... what is the coefficient of $x^{2022}$ in each of the terms on the last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{2023}$. The coefficient of the term of degree $2022$ of $x^{2023}+(1-x)^{2023}+\ldots$ is then $\binom{2023}{2022}=2023$.

Similarly (even without using binomial expansion) you can find the term of degree $2022$ of  the second part of your expression $x^{2022}+(1-x)^{2022}+\ldots$.